# What's the status of F# 4.6 in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017

F# 4.6 was released for Visual Studio 2019 (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-4-6/) but will features and tooling from F# 4.6 every be available for Visual Studio 2017 (namely, I'm interested in anonymous types)?

I have Nightly Releases configured for Visual F# Tools in my installation of Visual Studio 2017, but attempting to update to the latest gives me an installation error (latest version has min VS version targeting VS 16.0, i.e. Visual Studio 2019):

> 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM -
>   ------------------------------------------- 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version: 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM - 16.1.42 4/22/2019
>   9:32:08 AM - ------------------------------------------- 4/22/2019
>   9:32:08 AM - Command line parameters: 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM -
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Pro,/skuVersion:15.0.28307.586,/appidname:Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Professional
>   2017,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\steph\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIX4htuqo2p.vsix
>   4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM - -------------------------------------------
>   4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM -
>   ------------------------------------------- 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM - Initializing Install... 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM - Extension Details...
>   4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM -    Identifier         : VisualFSharp 4/22/2019
>   9:32:08 AM -  Name               : Visual F# Tools 4/22/2019 9:32:08
>   AM -  Author             : Microsoft.VisualFSharpTools 4/22/2019
>   9:32:08 AM -  Version            : 16.0.20190420.1922001 4/22/2019
>   9:32:08 AM -  Description        : Deploy Visual F# Tools Binaries to
>   Visual Studio 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM -  Locale             : en-US
>   4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM -    MoreInfoURL        :
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/ 4/22/2019
>   9:32:08 AM -  InstalledByMSI     : False 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM -
>     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.6,) 4/22/2019 9:32:08 AM - 
>   4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -    SignatureState     : ValidSignature 4/22/2019
>   9:32:10 AM -  SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation 4/22/2019
>   9:32:10 AM -  Certificate Info   :  4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -
>         ------------------------------------------------------- 4/22/2019
>   9:32:10 AM -      [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC,
>   O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US 4/22/2019
>   9:32:10 AM -      [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010,
>   O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US 4/22/2019
>   9:32:10 AM -      [Serial Number] :
>   330000026ECE6AE5984BFC96A900000000026E 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -         [Not
>   Before]    : 9/6/2018 5:00:30 PM 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -       [Not After] 
>   : 9/6/2019 5:00:30 PM 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -      [Thumbprint]    :
>   99B6246883B4B32EA59AE18B36945D205A876800 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM - 
>   4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -    Supported Products :  4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -
>         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -           Version :
>   [16.0,) 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -  4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -    References
>   :  4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -     Prerequisites      :  4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM
>   -         ------------------------------------------------------- 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -      Identifier   :
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -
>         Name         : Visual Studio core editor 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -
>         Version      : [16.0,) 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -  4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM
>   - Signature Details... 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -     Extension is signed with a valid signature. 4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -  4/22/2019 9:32:10 AM -
>   VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
>   installable on any currently installed products.    at
>   VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath,
>   String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData
>   stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.ComputeInstallableExtensions(IStateData
>   stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported, Boolean isExtensionPack,
>   IDictionary`2 skuDataMapping, IList`1 installableExtensionsPaths)
>
>   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
>   exceptionObject)

Comment: In effect VS 2017 is already abandonware. You might find this thread on Reddit interesting: https://www.reddit.com/r/fsharp/comments/bbf7qy/will_visual_studio_2017_bugs_be_fixed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nightly channel is a representation of latest `master` in the F# codebase, which requires Visual Studio 2019 if you are using it in Visual Studio. Note that the compiler can be used independently of tooling.

If you wish to use F# 4.6 in Visual Studio, you should upgrade to VS 2019.